# React useContext returns nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a React app in need of a reusable confirmation dialog box. This component displays a history list with a button to clear the history. I'd like to show a confirmation dialog.When the user clicks the *Clear History* button I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: confirmClear is not a function
    _callee$ HistoryPanel.js:18
    Babel 2
    node_modules main.js:133
    Babel 2
    node_modules main.js:35708
    node_modules main.js:35697
    handleClear HistoryPanel.js:17
    React 14
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 15
    js index.js:6
    Webpack 3
```

**How do I set the *confirmClear* function?**

HistoryPanel.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory, useHistoryDispatch } from './HistoryProvider'
import useConfirmDialog from "./ConfirmDialog"


export default function HistoryPanel({formatting}) {
  const history = useHistory()
  const historyDispatcher = useHistoryDispatch()
  const confirmClear = useConfirmDialog()

  function display(entry) {
    return( <li key={entry.id}>
              <time dateTime={entry.id}>{new Intl.DateTimeFormat(formatting.locale, formatting.dateFormat).format(entry.id)}</time> {entry.entry}
            </li> )
  }

  const handleClear = async () => {
    const ans = await confirmClear()
    if( ans ) { historyDispatcher({type: "clear"})}
  }
  
  function sorter(a,b) {
    return a.id - b.id
  }
  
  return(
    <section id="history">
      <h1>History</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClear}>Clear History</button>
      <ul className="history">
        { history.sort(sorter).map(display) }
      </ul>
    </section>
  )
}
```

ConfirmationDialog.js

```
// https://akashhamirwasia.com/blog/building-expressive-confirm-dialog-api-in-react/
import React, {
  createContext,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import Alert from "./Alert"


const ConfirmDialog = createContext();


export function ConfirmDialogProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isOpen: false });
  const fn = useRef();

  const confirm = useCallback(
    (data) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setState({ ...data, isOpen: true });
        fn.current = (choice) => {
          resolve(choice);
          setState({ isOpen: false });
        };
      });
    },
    [setState]
  );

  return (
    <ConfirmDialog.Provider value={confirm}>
      {children}
      <Alert
        {...state}
        onClose={() => fn.current(false)}
        onConfirm={() => fn.current(true)}
      />
    </ConfirmDialog.Provider>
  );
}


export default function useConfirmDialog() {
  return useContext(ConfirmDialog);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but it's completely redundant passing `setState` as a dependency to `useCallback()`; that value will never change

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the right modules? You've stated your file is `ConfirmationDialog.js` but you're importing from `ConfirmDialog`

Comment: Is `HistoryPanel` a descendant of `ConfirmDialogProvider`?

Comment: Seems reasonably obvious that your `HistoryPanel` is not under the context provider. Your default context value is `undefined` and `(undefined)()` results in _"is not a function"_

Comment: Btw you shouldn't use a ref here. Just call `state.onClose?.(); setState({ ...data, isOpen: true, onClose() { resolve(false) }, onConfirm() { resolve(true) } });`

Comment: Thanks y'all. I forgot to wrap HistoryPanel with the ConfirmDialogProvider.